# Trouble setting up postfix and dovecot. Folder permissions?

Tags: server, permissions, email, postfix

I've never posted on here so I will do my best to describe the issue. I am also pretty new to linux/ubuntu. (Using ubuntu 18.04)

Here goes:

I am trying to setup a mail server for my portfolio website I setup on my spare computer. I've got apache2, php, mysql installed and working. I had my share of issues getting to this point but alas, I digress.

My next step in setting up the server was to have my own mail server for my new website! Pretty exciting stuff.

I believe I've installed postfix and dovecot correctly but with my limited knowledge, I am left following tutorials. While I understand some of what is happening, most is still very much a foreign language to me.

When I display the status of both of these programs, it shows they are active(running) or active(exited). From what I could gather, they are running.

I've configured the dovecot_users file and I believe it's set up to use passwd? but then again I am not 100% sure.

My core issues:
I've installed roundcube and I've tried to connect using the e-mail and password I put in the dovecot_users file but I keep getting a storage server failed error.

When I try to connect to the server with thunderbird, it doesn't let me connect. I was getting a no connection issue but that seams to be gone now. Just can't connect. Says my password is wrong.

Now either I have mis-understood how to setup the dovecot users or maybe I have the wrong permissions for a folder? I am at a loss. Any help would be more than appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What OS/release are you talking about?  Specifics allow us to be specific in solutions.  If you get any messages, errors etc. providing these (and the commands that you tried that allowed you to see the messages) are also helpful.

Comment: I am using ubuntu 18.04